# Swift - How to avoid circular references in structs with parent and child relationships?

Tags: swift, struct, circular-reference

I have a relationship that can be described thusly;

> One `Parent` has many `Child` (Children)

```
struct Parent {
    var name: String
    var cost: Int
    var productionCost: Int
    var income: Int
    var children: [Child] = [Child]()

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

struct Child {
    var name: String
    var parent: Parent?
    var owner: Player?
}

// not used but the intention is to so a player can own a child
class Player {
   var name:
   var cards: [Child] = [Child]()
}
```

The parent needs to know about what children it has under it, and similarly the child needs to know about what parent it belongs to.

But in Swift playgrounds I noticed that there is a potential circular reference.

If I do;

```
var parent = Parent.init(name: "Parent #1")
var child = Child.init(name: "Child #1", parent: parent)

parent.children.append(child)

print (parent)
```

The swift playground reports;

[image]

The debug shows parents children, which in turns shows the parent, etc...

I understand that circular references aren't inheritantly bad but I would like to try to avoid them in a this described relationship.

I only want the first parent.

On other similar questions on StackOverflow, I've read that:

- "your child objects should be dumb data objects, they do not know anything about their parent and are self contained"
- "the parent just holds child objects, it does not inject itself into them"

But I'm not sure how that helps as I need to know what parent a child belongs to.

My question is;

How can I avoid the circular reference in the structs when I need to assign relationships to both sides?

Comment: The `struct` types are value types. So your attempt to have the child have reference back to parent doesn't quite make sense, because you're really creating a copy of the parent. This sort of two-way linking only makes sense with reference types.

Comment: And why are you trying to do this? You know that this way  your struct makes copies of the parent? What you want to do would make sense with classes, not structs.

Comment: Oh okay, so I guess use a class instead?  But for what party, the parent, the child or both?

Comment: Okay, I was under the impression that a struct would be better; but I understand the point of copies

Comment: The project I'm working is a "game" where there is a collection of cards in a deck.  Each card (the child) has a reference to what deck (the parent) its in. But in my query I abstracted away all the irrelevant stuff about the cards and deck for my query.

Comment: If children need references back to parent, then parent should be `class`. And once you've introduced reference semantics in your model, I'd probably make both classes (though, theoretically, the child could be a `struct`). But I'd step back and ask yourself whether you _really_ need the child to keep reference to its parent. You sometimes don't need that and you might want to not sacrifice the benefits of value semantics unless you have to. For example, do you really need to know which deck a card is in? Or when dealing with a given card, do you always already know which deck you're using?

Comment: Thats an interesting thought.  I've made my structs now classes so i can keep references.  The reference is needed because a player owns multiple cards.  He needs to know what card he owns. Thus its a reference not a copy.   But the card itself may potentially be a struct because there are multiple copies of cards; and all that's changing is the values.    I'm considering only making the parent and owners (players) references.  I'll experiement with both on playgrounds and do some simple tests and go with references or structs based upon this.

Comment: Nothing that you've described so far tells me that you really need these bidirectional references and therefore you might not need reference types at all. E.g. Do you ever need to know "who holds the Q♡" or do you really only need to know "what cards does player X hold?" But, hey, use reference types if you want. Many of us are Crusty and came from a world of reference types so it's sometimes hard to grok programming in value types. See [Building Better Apps with Value Types in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/414/).

Comment: Amended the code for the parent struct; to make it clear that the parent and child objects are different.  Thanks for the video, I will review it

Comment: The best way I can describe the relationship I'm modelling is `Factory -< Engines    Engine >-Player`   The player holds a card (engine) but that card needs a reference to what factory (parent) it is so that we can do a `one to many through`;  so it appears references are what I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use classes for this. Your struct is creating a copy of the parent, not a reference.

```
class Parent {
    var name: String
    var children: [Child] = [Child]()

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

class Child {
    var name: String
    weak var parent: Parent?
    init(name:String,parent: Parent) {
        self.name = name
        self.parent = parent
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, understood I will now accept your answer.  I think I was trying to be too clever of using structs.   Answer now accepted.

Comment: If you really want to use this "parent has array of children and child has reference to parent" model, I think it's dangerous to have `init` (or any method for that matter) that sets one relationship and not the other. It's a sure fire way of getting into trouble. You want to make sure that any methods that changes the `parent` of a `Child` also changes the `children` of the affected parents, too. If you expose methods that affect one relationship and not the other, you're only begging for them to get out of sync.

Comment: In this example I was just making it 1:1 to his code in structs, but there are dozens of ways to make it better. We explained to him that he cannot use structs. And that reference was not a reference but a new copy. That was the whole point of his question. He said he is well aware of how these things work. But he asked a question that had to be answered different than what he originally wanted. So the most basic answer with telling him that reference part of the answer. But I get what you are saying. Feel free to edit my answer if you want.